# Unable to create tasks in Windows task scheduler - Permission denied

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, permissions, windows-server-2016, task-scheduler

I have few servers facing same problem- I am unable to create task scheduler jobs. The problem seems to be exactly same as [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/53327/unable-to-create-scheduled-tasks) and [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/67734412-bb17-42d5-80ff-0edf3147c169/cannot-create-scheduled-task-access-denied?forum=winserverGP). 
However, I have checked group policies, and made sure that there is no policy in place to deny write permission on %SystemRoot%\Tasks folder. 
I also run the command `CACLS TASKS /E /G builtin\administrators:F` to make sure that administrators have permissions on the folder.

However there is no luck. I am unable to access the folder via Windows Explorer, but I can navigate to it through an elevated command prompt, means the permissions are in place. Also, I have compared the permissions on a working server and a non working server using `AccessEnum.exe`, which returns same result. I have Windows 2008 R2, 2012 R2 and 2016 servers facing this issue.

In this case, what else can be done to fix the problem ?

Comment: Check '%systemroot%\system32\tasks\'

Comment: the permissions are there, but unable to access

Comment: What are the permissions?

Comment: Administrators have full access. Do you need the full permissions for all users ?

Comment: Please see the screenshot :https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gvEoqg5rXd2XsysmdxagJxRf8IH3Kvon/view?usp=sharing